# Why is my Minecraft launcher not working?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, windows-7, minecraft-launcher

I need help because my Minecraft launcher doesn't work...

It's been a long time I haven't played Minecraft and until now it worked nicely. But now that I want to play on it again and I run the launcher, this appears (click images to enlarge):

[image]

At the bottom left of the screen the profile names keep loading (normally my username appears in the box) and as you can see I am unable to click on the "Play" button.

I tried creating another profile but it doesn't work because soon after they ask to enter my Minecraft username and password. The password I entered disappears and it keeps loading (I've tried waiting like, 30 minutes and it still doesn't work) so this is definitely not normal.

[image]

[image]

[image]

So basically I can't play on Minecraft anymore (version 1.7.9)...

P.S. I use Windows 7.

Comment: Have you tried the usual fixes? Completely reinstall minecraft (delete the .minecraft folder) and/or update Java. According to [this thread](http://www.minecraftforum.net/topic/1969579-when-i-start-the-launcher-its-stuck-loading-profiles/) installing Java 8 might help if you haven't done so already.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The launcher seems to be old, try getting the latest version here: http://s3.amazonaws.com/Minecraft.Download/launcher/Minecraft.exe